# Adding a select for foreign key object serverfireteam/panel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm using the Serverfireteam LaravelPanel (which uses zofe/rapyd-laravel
). I created a crud controller for an entity. This entity has a foreign key to another table. Now i want to show an autocomplete for this foreign key but it shows just an empty selectbox.

my Controller code look like this:

```
 public function  edit($entity){

    parent::edit($entity);
    $this->edit = \DataEdit::source(new \App\Regal());
    $this->edit->add('bezeichnung', 'Bezeichnung','text');
    $this->edit->add('nummer', 'Nummer','text');
    $this->edit->add('maxPaletten', 'Max Paletten je Ebene','text');
    $this->edit->add('anzahlEbenen', 'Anzahl Ebenen','text');

    $this->edit->add('kunde_id','Kunde','select')->options(\App\Kunde::lists("name", "id"));


    return \View::make('regale.editPanel', array(
        'title'          => $this->entity ,
         'edit' => $this->edit
        )); 


}
```

And my Model files:

```
class Kunde extends Model {

protected $table = 'kunden';
public function listPaletten(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Palette');
}
public function listAdressen(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Adresse');
}
public function listRegale(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Regal');
}
public function listArtikel(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Artikel');
}
}
```

..

```
class Regal extends Model {

protected $table = 'regale';

public function kunde(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Kunde');        
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example output of `\App\Kunde::lists("name", "id")`?

Comment: The output is:
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#365 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(2) { [1]=> string(7) "cookmal" [2]=> string(8) "schaumal" } }

Comment: Wired! According to Laravel documentation `lists()` method should return an array and not a collection. Probably casting the collection to an array would help: `\App\Kunde::lists("name", "id")->toArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using options method, options method is used for selectbox .

As it is explained in the [document](http://laravelpanel.com/docs/master/crud-fields) :

autocomplete (input field with autocomplete feature using twitter typeahead and ajax features using relation.fieldname and search() method )

```
$this->edit->add('author.fullname', 'Author', 'autocomplete')->search(array('firstname', 'lastname'));
```